# How to exit conversation in DialogFlow Fullfilment for an Action

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, fulfillment

I have an action which is a simple word game and upon completing the game should exit the conversation. I want the action to support `Google Assistant` and speaker based devices ( mobile phone etc) so i am handling the intent in a general fashion.

```
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
...
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  ...
  function answerIntent(agent) {
     if (gameShouldEnd) {
       agent.end("Your score is 3/5. Cheers! GoodBye!");
     }
  }
  ...
}
```

This results in log error `MalformedResponse: 'final_response' must be set`

I tried the conv api too and that results in the same error.

```
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
...
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  ...
  function answerIntent(agent) {
    if (gameShouldEnd) {
      let conv = agent.conv();
      conv.tell("Your score is 3/5. Cheers! GoodBye!");
      agent.add(conv);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Please suggest how to close the **Mic** when the game ends and still sends a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is an issue with version `0.5.0` of the `dialogflow-fullfillment` package according to the issue logged https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/149

I tried updating to `0.6.0` which has breaking changes which solved the current question i posted but created context related problems.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried the `close` method:

```
  conv.close("Your score is 3/5. Cheers! GoodBye!");
```

Comment: This is the right thing to do, but i had problem coz of the version of the `dialogflow-fullfilment` version i had

Answer (score 0):

please check if the lifespam of your intent is 1. After that you can use the command bellow:

agent.end("bye");

Comment: What's the best way to clear the lifespan of the intent?  I tried to do agent.clearOutgoingContexts() before i called agent.end() but it's still leaving the mic open for a response.